# How can I sort a python list of files by ordered list of file extensions

Tags: python

How would one order a list of files based on a specified order or file extensions? The reason I'm doing this is because I want to loop through the files and later process them in order of priority. which in this case is FBX. As a last resort I would use the EXR.

```
files = [
    'Z:/users/john/apples.jpg',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.fbx',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.exr',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.abc',
]

ext = ['fbx','abc', 'jpg', 'exr']`
```

The desired goal

```
>>> files = [
    'Z:/users/john/apples.fbx',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.abc',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.jpg',
    'Z:/users/john/apples.exr',
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort using the key `index` in the lookup `list`,

```
>>> import os
>>> files
['Z:/users/john/apples.jpg', 'Z:/users/john/apples.fbx', 'Z:/users/john/apples.exr', 'Z:/users/john/apples.abc']
>>> ext = ['fbx', 'abc', 'jpg', 'exr']
>>> sorted(files, key=lambda x: ext.index(os.path.splitext(x)[1].strip('.'))) # noqa
['Z:/users/john/apples.fbx', 'Z:/users/john/apples.abc', 'Z:/users/john/apples.jpg', 'Z:/users/john/apples.exr']
```

To handle, missing keys,

```
>>> files.append('foo.bar')
>>> keys = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(ext)}
>>> sorted(files, key=lambda x: keys.get(os.path.splitext(x)[1].strip('.'), float('inf')))
['Z:/users/john/apples.fbx', 'Z:/users/john/apples.abc', 'Z:/users/john/apples.jpg', 'Z:/users/john/apples.exr', 'foo.bar']
```

Comment: Very clever approach. I guess it would be safest for me to make this into a function to take into account ext that may not exist in the predefined list, as i would want those to be last.

Comment: yeah i didn't think about missing ext. Makes it a bit more tricky haha.

Comment: @JokerMartini Updated, it to handle the missing keys

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict that maps extensions to indices for use as a key for sorting:

```
indices = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(ext)}
sorted(files, key=lambda s: indices[s.rsplit('.', 1)[1]])
```

This returns:

```
['Z:/users/john/apples.fbx', 'Z:/users/john/apples.abc', 'Z:/users/john/apples.jpg', 'Z:/users/john/apples.exr']
```